# Angular4: How to re-initialize form control after adding an attribute on the fly

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So, I have made a form input component that takes an "extra" parameter where I can set some extra input attributes, something like this:

```html
  <form-input
    type="text"
    name="email"
    label="Form control 1"
    placeholder="Please enter your email"
    [(ngModel)]="demo.name"
    ngDefaultControl
    [extra] = "{minlength:2}"
  ></form-input>
```

and in the source:

```js
  @ViewChild('input') private _inputEl: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(changes['extra']){
      if(this._inputEl && this._inputEl.nativeElement){
        let attrs = Object.keys(this.extra);
        attrs.forEach(attr => {
          this._inputEl.nativeElement.setAttribute(attr, this.extra[attr]);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

the view is something like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">{{label}}</label>
  <input
    #input
    [name]="name"
    [type]="type"
    [value]="value"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="ngModel"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    #name="ngModel"
  >


  <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
    Lorem text
  </div>
</div>
```

but, the angular validation doesn't kick in for the input box.... but in the inspector I see the attribute being set properly.

If I put the minlength directly to the input element, the validation works OK

Comment: That's because `minlength` is not only an element attribute, but [a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L188-L215) that adds a validator to the formControl. You cannot add directives dynamically to elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minlength` is not just an attribute added to an HTML element, it is a directive that adds the control to the associated `FormControl` :

From the [Angular 4 sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L188-L215):

> ```js
> export const MIN_LENGTH_VALIDATOR: any = {
>   provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
>   useExisting: forwardRef(() => MinLengthValidator),
>   multi: true
> };
>
> /**
>  * A directive which installs the {@link MinLengthValidator} for any `formControlName`,
>  * `formControl`, or control with `ngModel` that also has a `minlength` attribute.
>  *
>  * @stable
>  */
> @Directive({
>   selector: '[minlength][formControlName],[minlength][formControl],[minlength][ngModel]',
>   providers: [MIN_LENGTH_VALIDATOR],
>   host: {'[attr.minlength]': 'minlength ? minlength : null'}
> })
> export class MinLengthValidator implements Validator,
>     OnChanges {
>   private _validator: ValidatorFn;
>   private _onChange: () => void;
>
>   @Input() minlength: string;
>
>   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
>     if ('minlength' in changes) {
>       this._createValidator();
>       if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
>     }
>   }
>
>   validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
>     return this.minlength == null ? null : this._validator(c);
>   }
>
>   registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }
>
>   private _createValidator(): void {
>     this._validator = Validators.minLength(parseInt(this.minlength, 10));
>   }
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, you cannot apply directives on-the-fly upon elements.

I fear the way-to-go would be to implement your own validation directive that will handle the object you are passing. You can take the provided code as a base to do this, that does not sound like a huge challenge.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to re-init this directive... at least it should be :)... thanks!